# Como acceder al user id del usuario logeado via fb api con lo generado por mvc en visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-api

necesito de alguna manera, guardar el user id que me devuelve fb con el user access token, o de alguna manera necesito acceder a el.
Estoy usando el código autogenerado de mvc para autentificarse con otros metodos.
O necesito entender de alguna manera como el id creado en mi base de datos del usuario logeado tiene que ver con el user-id que me trae el user-access-token la api de fb.

Comment: En si que tienes puedes poner tu codigo y un ejemplo del valor de tu access token, por ejemplo dices que tu aplicacion valida al usuario es decir ya tienes el valor de tu usuario en la sesion del lado servidor, podrias crear un metodo para obtener al usuario en la sesion y validarlo usando el token que tienes del lado del cliente.

Comment: Logre encontrar, el callback del external login, crea un objeto, el cual, dentro de sus properties Login.ProviderKey es con el cual asociamos la cuenta de fb con la cuenta de nuestro programa.

Comment: pues @Loprete Genararo solo agrega un nuevo metodo y devuelve ese ProviderKey como respuesta.